# How to use plt.hist() to plot a histogram out of a 1-D tensor without enabling eager execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

What I want to do is to write a function which can convert a one dimensional tensor to a numpy array and plot a histogram out of it using plt.hist().

Uptil now I have tried doing this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
one_dimensional_tensor = tf.constant([1, 2., 3., 4., 5.], dtype = np.float64)
one_dimensional_tensor_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype = np.float64, shape = sess.run(tf.shape(one_dimensional_tensor)))
n = plt.hist(one_dimensional_tensor_placeholder, bins = 'auto')[0]
bins = plt.hist(one_dimensional_tensor_placeholder, bins = 'auto')[1]
sess.run(n, feed_dict = {one_dimensional_tensor_placeholder: one_dimensional_tensor})
```

The above as is clearly visible will give an error telling that a placeholder cannot be fed value using a tensor as `one_dimensional_tensor` is a tensor.

I do not initially know the value of `one_dimensional_tensor`, it is the intermediate output of some prior computation, so I cannot do this:

```
n = plt.hist([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], bins = 'auto')[0]
```

I do not want to use [tf.histogram_fixed_width()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/histogram_fixed_width) as it uses only one binning technique in which the bin widths are fixed unlike [plt.hist()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) which provides a variety of binning techniques.
Is there any way to do this without enabling eager execution?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to write a function that you can pass your tensor into, but that will not evaluate that tensor and perform the plotting until some future time which you can specify. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarcusLim , not quite, my question centers more around "I want to plot a histogram using plt.hist(), obtain the n, bins and patches value for later processing, and I do not want to use tf.histogram_fixed_width() for the same".